# want to make a scrollable and clickable div with 5 different images on Mobile Responsives

Tags: javascript, html, css

i apologize if my title is not clear enough..please forgive my broken English..

I want to do something like this [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRC7e.png)

what I thought of is,

Here's some sample of the code, and this is my codepen https://codepen.io/jesmonong/pen/qBqNWNO

```
// mobile Javascript

var exp = document.getElementsByClassName('sections-mob')
var cont = document.getElementsByClassName('container-mob')
  for (var i = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
  exp[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    // Since HTML collection is not an array. We convert it like so
    var current = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("actives"))
 
    // If there are any active items remove them 
    if(current.length > 0){
      let node = current[0]
      node.classList.remove('actives');
      let nodeInfo = node.querySelector('.info-mob')
      nodeInfo.style.width = 200 + 'px';
      nodeInfo.style.opacity = 0;
      nodeInfo.style.height = 'auto';
      nodeInfo.style.transform = 'translateX(-200)';
      nodeInfo.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       nodeInfo.style.display = 'none';
       
    }else{
      this.className += " actives";
      let infoText = this.querySelector('.info-mob');
        let cont1 = this.querySelector('container-mob');
      // overflow.scrollLeft += this.scrollWidth;
        cont1.style.overflow = 'visible';
      infoText.style.width = 500 + 'px';
      infoText.style.opacity = 1;
      infoText.style.height ="auto";
      infoText.style.padding=20+"px"
      infoText.style.fontSize =0.5+"vw"
      infoText.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
      infoText.style.visibility = 'visible';
        infoText.style.display = 'flex';
    }
    
  });
}
    
  
  

// // draggable elements

const slider = document.querySelector('.container-mob');

let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.classList.add("actives")

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 3; //scroll-fast
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft
  console.log(walk);
});
```

I able to make the div scrollable and also when click, the info tab that keeps contents will show up below the image,

but i got difficulties making the info tab full width and align properly like the image sample , and also i wanted to make the image align on center and push the other images away..

sorry, I'm someone who wanted to be a better programmer, and I'm learning >.<
hopefully, anyone can give me some guidance on what should I actually do so that I can do research about it

Im still sorry about my English!
thanks!

Comment: About the width, the info tab (.info-mob) _is_ full width (which is the default for divs, that are `display:block` unless you override it). Only the text needs to be centered (text-align:center). I see you have many `id="expand"`. You can't have that. ID must be unique across the DOM. And last, if you want to center things, there's nothing like [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which is not a plugin or a library, but directly part of CSS. Happy learning :)